sequence converging and property
Assume $x_n\rightarrow x$ where $X$ is a metric space, and $x_n\neq x$ for all $n$. Then is it true that up to a subsequence we may assume that $x_n\neq x_m$ for all $n\neq m$?
(If we don't have requirement $x_n\neq x$ for all $n$ then it is false. Take $x_n=x$)
Proof idea:
Proof: Assume there exists a $n\neq m$ such that $x_n=x_m$. Consider sequence $(y_n)_n=(x_n)_{n\neq m}$ then $y_n\rightarrow x$. If $y_n= y_m$ for some $n\neq m$ then we may repeat process. So for all $n\neq m$, we may assume $y_n\neq y_m$.
Is thes  right?

@hamam_Abdallah see edit

The proof is a bit problematic because there might be infinite pairs of identical elements. For example, $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ when $n$ is even and $x_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$ is odd. Note that $x_n \to 0$. Applying your procedure to this sequence will result in a process that never ends, so you can’t produce the sequence $(y_n)_n$ this way.
Instead, note that any element of the sequence $(x_n)_n$ can only appear finitely many times. Otherwise, there is a subsequence that is constant, so must converge to that constant $x_{n_0}$ for some $n_0$. But it is a subsequence, so it must converge to $x$ as well. So, $x_{n_0} = x$, contradicting our assumptions. Hence, there are infinitely many distinct elements in the sequence $(x_n)_n$ and we may choose a subsequence consisting of each element exactly once.
If you want to be concrete, $(y_n)_n$ can be chosen inductively: let $y_1 = x_1$ and for any $n > 1$, set $y_n$ to be $x_{m_n}$ where $m_n$ is the smallest natural number such that $x_{m_n} \neq y_i$ for all $i < n$. Since there are infinitely many distinct $x$’s, this process is well-defined.

Note that the process I’m proposing is also never-ending, but by induction it does produce a sequence of elements of $X$, whereas your process will only produce, by induction, a sequence of sequences, not a sequence of elements of $X$ itself.

Assuming some form of choice is my method valid?

@monoidaltransform No. This has nothing to do with axiom of choice. A sequence of sequences is just not the same thing as a sequence of elements in $X$, regardless of axiom of choice. (You might be able to salvage your method by choosing $n$ and $m$ in a more systematic way and use the fact that each element only appears finitely many times in $(x_n)_n$. Then prove your sequence of sequences eventually stabilize at each $n$. But this just makes the argument a more complicated version of what I did in my answer.)
